# Uploading code to Arduino wirelessly

Tags: bluetooth, arduino-pro-mini, wireless

I have been working on a project watch which would work best if it is entirely sealed (to waterproof it). The watch may need future updates, but I will be unable to send code to it using a usb connector or isp programmer without opening the case. What is the best way to connect my PC with this watch wirelessly?

I gather that the serial ports are usually used to send code via the usb, and that most Bluetooth modules use serial coms to communicate with the Arduino.

The Arduino that I am using is an Arduino Pro Mini clone.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Go simple, and use light. IR-receiver or photo-transistor.

Comment: There actually exists an Arduino BT board. (https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardBT) which should be extremely easy (virtual bt COM-port as if it was connected to a cable). I'm not sure how up to date or available the board is though.

Comment: Alternatively, you could push a pin header through the box/casing, connect it, and cover it in hot glue. Which may be waterproof to some point.

Answer (score 1):

You could use ESP8266 and [ESP-LINK](https://github.com/jeelabs/esp-link) firmware to update the arduino firmware over the wire. Its also enables you to debug it wirelessly. What it does is provide a serial link but over wifi. Just like connecting it via cable.